# Dumpsys Meminfo reporting inconsistent values ((Free Ram + Used Ram + Lost Ram) > Total Ram) Nokia 1

Tags: adb, ram, android-go

Below is my log as stated in the title the value of Dumpsys Meminfo do not add up to total ram.

My device is NOKIA 1
Android 8.1.0

To reproduce these results I opened 10 apps using adb shell monkey and then took a dumpsys meminfo using This Command.

adb shell dumpsys -t 60 meminfo

My intution is

```
Free RAM + Used RAM + Lost RAM = Total RAM
416,633K + 760,054K + -17,123K = 1,159,564K

Total RAM (Though Summing) = 1,159,564 K
Total RAM (Reported by Dump Sys) = 951,952K
```

Why is there a difference in Total RAM ?

Here is the App list

```
com.google.android.youtube
com.google.android.apps.messaging
com.google.android.music
com.android.contacts
com.google.android.calculator
com.android.chrome
com.android.camera2
com.alibaba.aliexpresshd
com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping
com.cam001.selfie
com.daraz.android
```

I opened these apps with 20 second gaps to make sure that app opend completely.

```
  Total PSS by process:
       84,517K: com.google.android.apps.docs (pid 10596 / activities)
       71,280K: com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping (pid 10319 / activities)
       59,903K: com.alibaba.aliexpresshd (pid 9826 / activities)
       56,000K: system (pid 720)
       55,667K: com.hmdglobal.support (pid 10891)
       51,705K: com.android.systemui (pid 1161 / activities)
       40,915K: com.google.android.gms.persistent (pid 1529)
       32,720K: com.lenovo.anyshare.gps (pid 9140)
       29,314K: com.google.android.gms (pid 1680)
       24,049K: com.evenwell.UsageStatsLogReceiver (pid 9860)
       22,398K: com.android.chrome (pid 9588 / activities)
       20,676K: com.android.launcher3 (pid 1615 / activities)
       20,132K: com.uc.vmate (pid 7787)
       20,098K: com.google.android.inputmethod.latin (pid 1139)
       19,382K: video.like (pid 4663)
       18,346K: libweexjsb.so (pid 10111)
       18,100K: com.google.android.music:ui (pid 9020 / activities)
       18,004K: com.android.settings (pid 7279 / activities)
       16,362K: com.alibaba.aliexpresshd:channel (pid 10142)
       15,781K: com.android.vending (pid 7678)
       15,400K: com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0 (pid 9632)
       13,429K: com.google.android.calculator (pid 9502 / activities)
       12,023K: surfaceflinger (pid 289)
       11,217K: com.uc.vmate:rainbow (pid 7889)
       10,448K: com.lenovo.anyshare.gps:transfer (pid 8380)
       10,311K: video.like:service (pid 9926)
       10,020K: camerahalserver (pid 426)
        9,585K: com.google.android.music:main (pid 9039)
        9,373K: com.android.phone (pid 1323)
        7,786K: com.opera.browser.beta (pid 9724)
        7,629K: com.google.android.partnersetup (pid 10869)
        6,198K: com.mediatek.ims (pid 1316)
        5,358K: android.process.acore (pid 8929)
        4,348K: merged_hal_service (pid 282)
        4,096K: com.evenwell.OTAUpdate (pid 1570)
        4,094K: android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-service (pid 280)
        4,033K: com.google.process.gapps (pid 7909)
        4,033K: mediaserver (pid 420)
        3,900K: audioserver (pid 409)
        3,849K: android.hardware.audio@2.0-service-mediatek (pid 273)
        3,751K: vtservice (pid 415)
        3,652K: com.evenwell.pushagent (pid 1552)
        3,639K: android.process.media (pid 7353)
        3,613K: com.google.process.gservices (pid 1633)
        3,557K: media.codec (pid 424)
        3,472K: /init (pid 1)
        3,219K: com.evenwell.autoregistration (pid 7239)
        2,901K: zygote (pid 407)
        2,900K: drmserver (pid 413)
        2,883K: com.android.chrome:webview_service (pid 10008)
        2,823K: mtkmal (pid 297)
        2,705K: media.extractor (pid 419)
        2,701K: com.evenwell.batteryprotect (pid 7220)
        2,691K: mtkrild (pid 760)
        2,604K: mnld (pid 406)
        2,588K: rilproxy (pid 849)
        2,546K: com.android.smspush (pid 1708)
        2,539K: cameraserver (pid 411)
        2,444K: com.evenwell.emm (pid 1546)
        2,383K: com.android.partnerbrowsercustomizations (pid 9618)
        2,158K: mtk_agpsd (pid 432)
        1,825K: wpa_supplicant (pid 1241)
        1,414K: netd (pid 421)
        1,392K: android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service (pid 281)
        1,386K: vold (pid 262)
        1,313K: logd (pid 251)
        1,290K: android.hardware.drm@1.0-service.widevine (pid 278)
        1,237K: vendor.mediatek.hardware.wfo@1.0-service (pid 284)
        1,234K: wfca (pid 298)
        1,186K: ueventd (pid 205)
        1,157K: vendor.mediatek.hardware.pq@2.0-service (pid 435)
        1,151K: keystore (pid 417)
        1,123K: installd (pid 416)
        1,085K: wificond (pid 423)
        1,082K: aal (pid 408)
        1,068K: android.hardware.sensors@1.0-service-mediatek (pid 425)
          959K: ged_srv (pid 1516)
          958K: hwservicemanager (pid 253)
          857K: mediadrmserver (pid 418)
          852K: android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-service (pid 261)
          840K: gatekeeperd (pid 437)
          827K: dm_agent_binder (pid 412)
          797K: storaged (pid 422)
          787K: thermalserviced (pid 290)
          771K: android.hardware.broadcastradio@1.1-service (pid 275)
          734K: healthd (pid 285)
          715K: ccci_fsd (pid 292)
          703K: android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0-service-mediatek (pid 274)
          690K: android.hardware.cas@1.0-service (pid 276)
          669K: ccci_mdinit (pid 294)
          667K: vendor.mediatek.hardware.imsa@1.0-service (pid 283)
          665K: android.hardware.gatekeeper@1.0-service (pid 279)
          662K: ip6tables-restore (pid 481)
          659K: netdagent (pid 443)
          652K: adbd (pid 1503)
          637K: vtservice_hidl (pid 272)
          629K: android.hardware.configstore@1.0-service (pid 277)
          615K: fuelgauged (pid 291)
          598K: servicemanager (pid 252)
          569K: gsm0710muxd (pid 696)
          554K: epdg_wod (pid 442)
          553K: android.hidl.allocator@1.0-service (pid 271)
          553K: lmkd (pid 287)
          552K: dumpsys (pid 10758)
          541K: vndservicemanager (pid 254)
          541K: bbs_fih_log (pid 330)
          540K: program_binary_service (pid 438)
          516K: thermald (pid 414)
          511K: tombstoned (pid 441)
          510K: batterywarning (pid 410)
          485K: ipsec_mon (pid 430)
          457K: iptables-restore (pid 480)
          451K: pandoraservice (pid 306)
          424K: ccci_rpcd (pid 296)
          409K: sysenv_daemon (pid 434)
          405K: wifi2agps (pid 436)
          395K: thermal (pid 427)
          386K: wmt_launcher (pid 300)
          385K: storageproxyd (pid 444)

  Total PSS by OOM adjustment:
      204,221K: Native
           55,667K: com.hmdglobal.support (pid 10891)
           18,346K: libweexjsb.so (pid 10111)
           12,023K: surfaceflinger (pid 289)
           10,020K: camerahalserver (pid 426)
            7,629K: com.google.android.partnersetup (pid 10869)
            4,348K: merged_hal_service (pid 282)
            4,094K: android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-service (pid 280)
            4,033K: mediaserver (pid 420)
            3,900K: audioserver (pid 409)
            3,849K: android.hardware.audio@2.0-service-mediatek (pid 273)
            3,751K: vtservice (pid 415)
            3,557K: media.codec (pid 424)
            3,472K: /init (pid 1)
            2,901K: zygote (pid 407)
            2,900K: drmserver (pid 413)
            2,823K: mtkmal (pid 297)
            2,705K: media.extractor (pid 419)
            2,691K: mtkrild (pid 760)
            2,604K: mnld (pid 406)
            2,588K: rilproxy (pid 849)
            2,539K: cameraserver (pid 411)
            2,158K: mtk_agpsd (pid 432)
            1,825K: wpa_supplicant (pid 1241)
            1,414K: netd (pid 421)
            1,392K: android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service (pid 281)
            1,386K: vold (pid 262)
            1,313K: logd (pid 251)
            1,290K: android.hardware.drm@1.0-service.widevine (pid 278)
            1,237K: vendor.mediatek.hardware.wfo@1.0-service (pid 284)
            1,234K: wfca (pid 298)
            1,186K: ueventd (pid 205)
            1,157K: vendor.mediatek.hardware.pq@2.0-service (pid 435)
            1,151K: keystore (pid 417)
            1,123K: installd (pid 416)
            1,085K: wificond (pid 423)
            1,082K: aal (pid 408)
            1,068K: android.hardware.sensors@1.0-service-mediatek (pid 425)
              959K: ged_srv (pid 1516)
              958K: hwservicemanager (pid 253)
              857K: mediadrmserver (pid 418)
              852K: android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-service (pid 261)
              840K: gatekeeperd (pid 437)
              827K: dm_agent_binder (pid 412)
              797K: storaged (pid 422)
              787K: thermalserviced (pid 290)
              771K: android.hardware.broadcastradio@1.1-service (pid 275)
              734K: healthd (pid 285)
              715K: ccci_fsd (pid 292)
              703K: android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0-service-mediatek (pid 274)
              690K: android.hardware.cas@1.0-service (pid 276)
              669K: ccci_mdinit (pid 294)
              667K: vendor.mediatek.hardware.imsa@1.0-service (pid 283)
              665K: android.hardware.gatekeeper@1.0-service (pid 279)
              662K: ip6tables-restore (pid 481)
              659K: netdagent (pid 443)
              652K: adbd (pid 1503)
              637K: vtservice_hidl (pid 272)
              629K: android.hardware.configstore@1.0-service (pid 277)
              615K: fuelgauged (pid 291)
              598K: servicemanager (pid 252)
              569K: gsm0710muxd (pid 696)
              554K: epdg_wod (pid 442)
              553K: android.hidl.allocator@1.0-service (pid 271)
              553K: lmkd (pid 287)
              552K: dumpsys (pid 10758)
              541K: vndservicemanager (pid 254)
              541K: bbs_fih_log (pid 330)
              540K: program_binary_service (pid 438)
              516K: thermald (pid 414)
              511K: tombstoned (pid 441)
              510K: batterywarning (pid 410)
              485K: ipsec_mon (pid 430)
              457K: iptables-restore (pid 480)
              451K: pandoraservice (pid 306)
              424K: ccci_rpcd (pid 296)
              409K: sysenv_daemon (pid 434)
              405K: wifi2agps (pid 436)
              395K: thermal (pid 427)
              386K: wmt_launcher (pid 300)
              385K: storageproxyd (pid 444)
       56,000K: System
           56,000K: system (pid 720)
       77,468K: Persistent
           51,705K: com.android.systemui (pid 1161 / activities)
            9,373K: com.android.phone (pid 1323)
            6,198K: com.mediatek.ims (pid 1316)
            4,096K: com.evenwell.OTAUpdate (pid 1570)
            3,652K: com.evenwell.pushagent (pid 1552)
            2,444K: com.evenwell.emm (pid 1546)
       84,517K: Foreground
           84,517K: com.google.android.apps.docs (pid 10596 / activities)
       88,556K: Visible
           40,915K: com.google.android.gms.persistent (pid 1529)
           29,314K: com.google.android.gms (pid 1680)
           15,781K: com.android.vending (pid 7678)
            2,546K: com.android.smspush (pid 1708)
       20,098K: Perceptible
           20,098K: com.google.android.inputmethod.latin (pid 1139)
        6,858K: A Services
            3,639K: android.process.media (pid 7353)
            3,219K: com.evenwell.autoregistration (pid 7239)
       20,676K: Home
           20,676K: com.android.launcher3 (pid 1615 / activities)
       80,608K: B Services
           59,903K: com.alibaba.aliexpresshd (pid 9826 / activities)
           18,004K: com.android.settings (pid 7279 / activities)
            2,701K: com.evenwell.batteryprotect (pid 7220)
      320,869K: Cached
           71,280K: com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping (pid 10319 / activities)
           32,720K: com.lenovo.anyshare.gps (pid 9140)
           24,049K: com.evenwell.UsageStatsLogReceiver (pid 9860)
           22,398K: com.android.chrome (pid 9588 / activities)
           20,132K: com.uc.vmate (pid 7787)
           19,382K: video.like (pid 4663)
           18,100K: com.google.android.music:ui (pid 9020 / activities)
           16,362K: com.alibaba.aliexpresshd:channel (pid 10142)
           15,400K: com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0 (pid 9632)
           13,429K: com.google.android.calculator (pid 9502 / activities)
           11,217K: com.uc.vmate:rainbow (pid 7889)
           10,448K: com.lenovo.anyshare.gps:transfer (pid 8380)
           10,311K: video.like:service (pid 9926)
            9,585K: com.google.android.music:main (pid 9039)
            7,786K: com.opera.browser.beta (pid 9724)
            5,358K: android.process.acore (pid 8929)
            4,033K: com.google.process.gapps (pid 7909)
            3,613K: com.google.process.gservices (pid 1633)
            2,883K: com.android.chrome:webview_service (pid 10008)
            2,383K: com.android.partnerbrowsercustomizations (pid 9618)

  Total PSS by category:
      120,452K: .dex mmap
       85,362K: .so mmap
       77,628K: Native
       68,219K: .apk mmap
       65,610K: Dalvik
       46,060K: GL mtrack
       25,774K: .art mmap
       25,312K: Dalvik Other
       24,384K: Unknown
       16,813K: .oat mmap
       14,974K: EGL mtrack
       12,700K: Stack
       12,308K: Other mmap
        1,326K: Other dev
          730K: Ashmem
          709K: .ttf mmap
           76K: .jar mmap
            0K: Cursor
            0K: Gfx dev
            0K: Other mtrack

  Total RAM:   951,952K (status normal)
   Free RAM:   416,633K (  320,869K cached pss +    72,320K cached kernel +    23,444K free)
   Used RAM:   760,054K (  639,002K used pss +   121,052K kernel)
   Lost RAM:   -17,123K
       ZRAM:   104,800K physical used for   357,032K in swap (  428,372K total swap)
     Tuning: 128 (large 256), oom   184,320K, restore limit    61,440K (low-ram)
```

Addition Information DUMPSYS, VMSTAT

```
Total RAM:   951,952K (status normal)
 Free RAM:   420,263K (  286,451K cached pss +   112,720K cached kernel +    21,092K free)
 Used RAM:   729,271K (  610,175K used pss +   119,096K kernel)
 Lost RAM:    -7,523K
     ZRAM:    86,648K physical used for   322,252K in swap (  428,372K total swap)
   Tuning: 128 (large 256), oom   184,320K, restore limit    61,440K (low-ram)

C:\Users\ab>adb shell /system/bin/vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 4  1 318204  27884    900 335664  477  667  2422   747    0 2797 20 18 62  1

C:\Users\ab>adb shell /system/bin/free -k
                total        used        free      shared     buffers
Mem:           951952      903968       47984        1868         900
-/+ buffers/cache:         903068       48884
Swap:          428372      324320      104052
```

Comment: Do you have root? What's the output of `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/vmstat` and `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/free -k` and `/system/bin/vmstat` and `/system/bin/free -k`?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a rooted devices.

Comment: `free` command should still work, it just reads `/proc/meminfo`. Also try `vmstat`, may be you sepolicy allows reading `/proc/stat`.

Comment: I have added the results of vmstat and free command